# Google HTTP Target tasks: Expect Google\Protobuf\Timestamp when tried to setScheduleTime using php

Tags: php, laravel, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-tasks

I have been trying to add setScheduleTime to the cloud task. I have done the following:

```
use Google\Cloud\Tasks\V2\CloudTasksClient;
use Google\Cloud\Tasks\V2\HttpMethod;
use Google\Cloud\Tasks\V2\HttpRequest;
use Google\Cloud\Tasks\V2\Task;

class CreateRandomCloudTasksForLot
{
        putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/service-account.json');
        $client = new CloudTasksClient();
        $queueName = $client->queueName($this->projectID, $this->location, $this->queue);

        $httpRequest = new HttpRequest();
        $httpRequest->setUrl('https://europe-west1-myproject.cloudfunctions.net/mybidfunction?id=1');        
        $httpRequest->setHttpMethod(HttpMethod::GET);
        
        if (isset($payload)) {
            $httpRequest->setBody($payload);
        }

        // Create a Cloud Task object.
        $task = new Task();
        $task->setScheduleTime(strtotime(Carbon::now()->addMinutes(20)));
        $task->setHttpRequest($httpRequest);

        // Send request and print the task name.
        $response = $client->createTask($queueName, $task);
        printf('Created task %s' . PHP_EOL, $response->getName());
}
```

It gives me the following error
[image]

Without passing the scheduled time I can create tasks but I need to schedule at a specific time. I cannot use appEngineTask because we can pass only RelativeUri. I want to pass the cloud function URL to execute. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2):

I found the issue. Hope it will help someone because they have not mentioned in their document at all.

add this `use Google\Protobuf\Timestamp;`

```
        $future_time_seconds = time() + 300;
        $future_timestamp = new Timestamp();
        $future_timestamp->setSeconds($future_time_seconds);
        $future_timestamp->setNanos(0);
        $task->setScheduleTime($future_timestamp);
        $task->setHttpRequest($httpRequest);
```

Pass the object of Google\Protobuf\Timestamp to `setScheduleTime`. After digging into core files I figure out that it should be an object. The error should be more descriptive.

That's all :)

Comment: Thank you Dhara, that worked for me, I was digging through their docs as well and didn't realize that it needed to be an object.